# overriding css class on bootstrap datetime picker when selecting year

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to override css style on bootstrap datetime picker control when selecting years from default blue to let's say red. How can I do that?

I tried with

```
.selectYear {
    background-color:red!important;
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Update
I use 
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: You load bootstrap.css before or after your css file?

Comment: Which bootstrap datetime picker plugin are you using?

Comment: @SergiCase I load my style file after bootstrap.css

Comment: I've searched in plugin code and I haven't found any class like `selectYear`.  Please provide an image or show us on the plugin page (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) the actual element that you are trying to style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like 'selectYear' is a data attribute data-action="selectYear" and the class is 'year'

```
 data-action="selectYear" class="year active"
```

The css is what's adding the background

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span.active {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

So either

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span.year.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or

```
.year {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I've searched in plugin code and I haven't found any class name like `selectYear`.

Assuming that you want to style only the year selector panel, try with the following css rule:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span.year.active {
     background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Did not see an example. You use wring selector at all. `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span.active{background-color:red!important;}`; selectYear  - it`s a data action attribute value

Comment: Is this comment or an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.ui-datepicker-year{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: He's not using jQuery UI Datepicker.